# Can't access cookie store from android

Tags: android

I'm trying this

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

CookieStore cookieStore = httpClient.getCookieStore();

List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();
```

But I can't access the getCookieStore(). It just doesn't exist on the httpClient. The ony gets that are available are

```
httpClient.getClass()
httpClient.getConnectionManager()
httpClient.getParams()
```

nothing else.
I increased my api level but that still didn't work. Not sure what I need to do to access the cookies that are returned from a client?

Answer (score 1):

I changed HttpClient to DefaultHttpClient. i.e. I went from

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient()
```

to

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```